# Обособление оборота с "благодаря"

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли я обособила оборот с "благодаря"? И уж заодно правильно ли выделила вводное слово "соответственно"?

Также, благодаря использованию специальных сферических вырезов (1) и оптимизации профиля упругих уплотнений (2), достигается уменьшение крутящего момента на 35 % , что дает возможность выбирать меньший типоразмер привода, и, соответственно, уменьшать общую стоимость сборки затвор — привод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: Также, благодаря использованию специальных сферических вырезов  и оптимизации профиля упругих уплотнений***,*** достигается уменьшение крутящего момента на 35 %, что дает возможность выбирать меньший типоразмер привода, и, соответственно***,*** уменьшать общую стоимость сборки затвор — привод.

Answer (score 3):

Можно и не обособлять.

"Полный академический справочник "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации" выделяет ТОЛЬКО ОДНО обязательное условие обособления:

Обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями обязательно обособляются, если они располагаются **между подлежащим и сказуемым**: разрыв их непосредственной связи и способствует выделению оборотов. В других позициях такие обороты **могут не обособляться** (без необходимости подчеркивания). Ср.: ***Благодаря** дождям посевы зазеленели. — Посевы, **благодаря** дождям, зазеленели*.

У вас позиция не между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Грамота.ру (http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1/):

Однако возможны и иные варианты пунктуационного оформления, обусловленные замыслом автора. Например: *На следующее утро **благодаря** многочисленным пришельцам в четверть часа остов новой землянки был закончен* (В. Обручев, Земля Санникова) – невыделение оборота, находящегося не в начале и не в конце предложения.

И уберите запятую перед И.

Comment: Тат, вы хотите сказать, что здесь соответственно имеет значение: "соответствующим образом", "так, как требуется"? Здесь "соответственно" вводное слово.

Comment: Я про запятую ПЕРЕД И (однородные члены).

Answer (score 1):

Меня смущает запятая перед "и"

Answer (score 0):

Да, в этих случаях всё сделано правильно. 
У меня возникли сомнения относительно "тире" между словами "затвор  —  привод". На мой взгляд, между этими словами нужно ставить дефис, поскольку эти слова объединяются в одно понятие: "сборка затвор-привод", т.е. составляют единый механизм.

Comment: Да, если это единый механизм, то нужен дефис.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая перед И  не нужна, так как союз И связывает два однородных члена предложения "выбирать" и "уменьшать".